# http post call not working from angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, rest

I am new to AngularJS. I have included the code for the controller, service, and call to the rest service. Kindly advise why the call is not reaching the rest service.

My code is as follows:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider       
    .when('/addNewNote', {
     controller: 'AddNewNoteController',
     templateUrl:'views/addNote.html'
     })
```

the angularjs controller is as below

```
    app.controller('AddNewNoteController', ['$scope','savenote',        function($scope,savenote) {

    savenote.success(function(eData){
            $scope.msg = eData;
```

The angular service to call the http post rest service

```
 app.factory('savenote',['$http',function($scope,$http){

    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: <url is pasted here>,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
        "title" : "123dddd",
        "contents" : "123ddddtttttt"
    },
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' }
    })          

 }]);
```

This is the rest service

```
@Path("/savenote")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)  
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)  
  public UserMessages saveNewNote(Note note) throws IOException {       
   .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the type hint for `$scope`:

```
app.factory('savenote',['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http){
```

Also, your factory should return an object with methods:

```
app.factory('savenote', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    return {
        save: function () {
            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: "<url is pasted here>",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    "title": "123dddd",
                    "contents": "123ddddtttttt"
                },
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

And use it as follows:

```
savenote.send().then(function(eData) {});
```

Also, as @SarjanDesai stated in his comment, `$scope` is not used in your factory, so you should remove it.

Comment: In factory `$scope` is not used at all

Comment: Correct, i've added a note to my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I have changed the code to app.factory('savenote', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        save: function () {
            return $http({
                method: 'POST',....

Answer (score 0):

`savenote` returning `$http` object which has [then](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) function for calling success and failure callback.

So update your controller function with below:

```
savenote.then(function successCallback(eData) {
    $scope.msg = eData;   
}
```

> The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been
>   deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If
>   $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then these
>   methods will throw $http/legacy error.

Comment: 'views/addNote.html'  is as below...<form >
        <button type="reset" >Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
     
</form>